# Downloading pdf with urllib.requests writes a pdf that cannot be opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to download a pdf file from a website with authentication and save it locally. This code appears to run but saves a pdf file that cannot be opened ("it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged").

```
import urllib.request

auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm=None,
                   uri=r'http://website/',
                   user='admin',
                   passwd='pass')
opener =  urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
url = 'http://www.website.com/example.pdf'
res = opener.open(url)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "example.pdf")
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the downloaded file in a text or binary (hex) editor? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: Ah, the website's source code. I'm guessing this means my authentication is bad - probably the realm? I haven't been able to determine the realm.

Comment: It will take a quick install (`easy_install requests`), but you might try the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead, as it handles authentication more transparently

Comment: I'm trying this out with requests now and running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a bad URL. Make sure you get the ".pdf" file on your browser when you enter that URL in the browser.

EDIT:

I meant to say, your URL should be like this: "http://www.cse.msu.edu/~chooseun/Test2.pdf" Your code must be able to pull off this pdf from the web address. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that - doesn't seem to be the issue. The website redirects to login and I end up downloading the source code for the login page as a very confused pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with "urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "example.pdf")". After you get through the authentication save the file using something like this instead:

```
pdfFile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
file = open("example.pdf", 'wb')
file.write(pdfFile.read())
file.close()
```